# Simple edit component for Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, components, angular-bootstrap

I can not find dedicated (text) edit (input) component in Bootstrap suite. What is the best practice for using edit (input) components in Bootstrap powered projects? It isn't be nice if edit components looks and behaves differently from the other components in form.

Comment: What do you mean by "edit components"? text boxes? input fields?

Comment: text box, input field for text. Bootstrap seems to be so standartized and it has answer to almost any problem, so - I wanted to do this Bootstrap-style. I have no specific need, simply, I want to follow the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

All `<input>` types (single line input) and `<textarea>` (multi-line input) are styled in Bootstrap.

See the [Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms).

There are no other best practices specific to TWBS.  Remember, Bootstrap is a framework ... your UX is built on top of it, so UI is defined by you.